# how can I write the test cases for the method with in the method?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, code-coverage, testcase

```
    @Transactional
    public DeviceHistory createDeviceHistory(DeviceHistory dh) {
        Timestamp currentTime = CommonRoutines.getUTCTimestamp();

        dh.setCreatedAt(currentTime);
        dh.setUpdatedAt(currentTime);
        dh.setActive(1);

        GeneratedKeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        int rowCount = provJDBCTemplateRepository.executeUpdate(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(DeviceQueries.INSERT_INTO_DMS_DEVICE_HISTORIES,
                        new String[] { "LOG_ID" });

                statement.setString(1, dh.getTransactionId());
                statement.setObject(2, dh.getDeviceGroupId());
                statement.setString(3, dh.getEventType());
                statement.setString(4, dh.getMessageCode());
                statement.setString(5, dh.getMessageTextEnUS());
                statement.setObject(6, dh.getSmartAccountId());
                statement.setObject(7, dh.getVirtualAccountId());
                statement.setString(8, dh.getTenantId());
                statement.setObject(9, dh.getDeviceDetailId());
                statement.setString(10, dh.getSeverity());
                statement.setObject(11, dh.getHasAPICEMLog());
                statement.setObject(12, dh.getParentLogId());
                statement.setObject(13, dh.getActive());
                statement.setString(14, dh.getCreatedBy());
                statement.setTimestamp(15, dh.getCreatedAt());
                statement.setString(16, dh.getUpdatedBy());
                statement.setTimestamp(17, dh.getUpdatedAt());

                return statement;
            }
        }, holder);

        LOGGER.debug("Rows Updated createDeviceAlerts- ", rowCount);
        dh.setLogId(Long.valueOf(holder.getKey().toString()));
        return dh;
    }
```

```
    @Test
    public void testcreateDeviceHistory()throws Exception{
        try {
        DeviceHistory deviceHistory=new DeviceHistory();
        deviceHistory.setActive(1);
        deviceHistory.setCreatedAt(null);
        deviceHistory.setCreatedBy("");
         new MockUp<DeviceDaoImpl>() {
                @mockit.Mock
                public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {    
                    PreparedStatement statement =con.prepareStatement(anyString(),new String[] { "LOG_ID" });
                    statement.setString(1,"");
                    statement.setObject(2,"");
                    statement.setString(3,"");
                    statement.setString(4,"");
                    return statement;
                }
            };
        
        GeneratedKeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();       
        deviceDaoImpl.createDeviceHistory(deviceHistory);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

help me out how we can write the test case for the methods createPreparedStatement with in the createQueueMessage method. I tries with this but showing very less coverage .In test class i am not able to enter into the PreparedStatementCreator block. I mocked all the required class in test class. I am not sure where i am missing.could you please help me out.

Comment: Your test doesn't seem to call `createQueueMessage` at all.